# how to push key and value in array using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter data on the basis of number of rows and columns provided by user.

I am getting the data on controller after reading this excel file:

[image]

this is the column header values which I am getting after user has passed 5 as input columns:
[image]

This is the row data which I am getting after user has given 4 rows as input to be rendered, here there is data of 4 rows:
[image]

Inside each row, there is key value pair containing column name and the cell value:

[image]

I want to filter this row data on the basis of the header names which are coming through column so that the row has only the values till the column is defined. Currently I am getting entire row values.

I have written a logic like this but this is not working.

```
var rowData=[];
for(var i=0;i<headerNames.length;i++){//headerNames contains column names
   for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){//data contains the rows data
      for(var keyName in data[j])
        if(angular.equals(keyName,headerNames[i])){
           rowData.push({'keyName':data[j][keyName]})//I want only the key,values which matches the column names. I want to set the keyName value as array key but I am not getting its value instead it is coming like keyName:18
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Adding the plunker for the code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/28Z44xDBug7nFCQnKZJL?p=preview

I am able to filter the data on UI and get only the row and column data as per user input.
But i need the same data on controller, so that i can save it in MongoDb. I want to filter the row data as per the column input. So, that i only get the row data till the column is defined.

Please suggest how can i filter the data and can splice the row values so that in row i can have value upto the column numbers defined. For eg, if I user have entered 4 rows and 5 columns then in my row Data i can have only values upto 5th column and all other values i can remove from array. in my code currently i am not able to get the key value to be set as array key.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not in images. It should be such that we can reproduce the problem ourselves. Also, there's actually little angular-specific code here; you might try searching without including angular in your search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're most of the way there. You just need to assign rowData to be $scope.rowData so that angular can get to it, and have the Angular document show {{rowdata}} (shows $scope.rowData).

You'll probably need to arrange it into columns though so you might do a ng-repeat on rowData, with variable=row, and in TR TD tags show row.1

eg something like ..

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowData">
<td>{{row.1}}</td>
<td>{{row.2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No, actually I need that values on controller itself, as I need to pass the data to mongodb for saving. So, basically i need the data which has user defined rows and column values only. for eg if user has entered 4 rows and 5 columns so the data i need is 5 column header and row data upto 5th column only.